# What is the type in this template?

Tags: c++, templates

```
std::tr1::_Bind<void (*()(std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>))(int&)>
```

I understand `std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>` and this whole thing is some sort of function pointer that returns `void` and takes `int&` as argument. But I can't seem to follow the ***()** in the beginning. The code's cut-pasted from some gdb session i was going through a while back.

Also, what is the type to tr1::function? Some function which returns void and takes no argument?

```
0x00000001000021a1 in std::tr1::function<void ()()>::operator() (this=0x7fff5fbffb98) at functional_iterate.h:865
```

But then the following is an error:

```
template <typename T>
void f()
{ 
  cout << "general\n";
}

template<>
void f<void ()()> () // this is error
{
  cout << "specific\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an instance of `std::tr1::_Bind` instantiated on the type of a function taking a `std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>` and returning a pointer to a function taking a reference to int and returning void.

Here's how to read it:

- `std::tr1::_Bind<`*type*`>` should be clear.
- *type* = `void (`*fn*`)(int&)` is a function taking `int&` and returning `void`.
- *fn* = `*`*ptr* so it's actually a pointer to function
- *ptr* = `(`*fn2*`)(std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>)` is a function taking `std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>` and what we had up to now is its return type.
- *fn2* = (empty) because we don't give that function (type) a name.

However as I now notice when the *fn2* is empty, the parentheses around it should probably also not be there (similar to how you write the function type "function taking no parameters and returning void" as `void()`, not `void()()`.

The case in `std::tr1::function` is exactly that one: A function taking no parameters and returning `void`, with extra parentheses around the empty "function name".

OK, now tested it: gdb indeed outputs `void()` as `void()()`; this probably should be considered a gdb bug.

The correct way to write the first type in C++ therefore is:

```
std::tr1::_Bind<void (*(std::tr1::reference_wrapper<int>))(int&)>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the star be between the two parenthesis for that?

Comment: @6502: No, because the star belongs to the *return type* of the function (which itself is a function, and for *that* function the star is indeed inside the corresponding parentheses.

Comment: @Fanatic23: I was already in the process of writing that up. It just took some time.

Comment: +1. Still a bit confused, albeit in a related problem of what the type to std::tr1::function is in this case, and why the same type to a function results in error.

Comment: @Fanatic23: The type to `std::tr1.:function is just a function taking no argument and returning `void`; you'd normally enter it just as `void()`. I now notice that the empty parentheses in the other case probably also should not be there, so maybe the printing of those is probably a gdb bug. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I just mean that for example `void (*)(int)` is a pointer to a function accepting an `int` and returning `void`. I didn't know `void *()(int)` could have any meaning in C++.

Comment: @6502: Well, as I didn't initially notice, but have written in my edit, the extra parentheses are spurious and only inserted by gdb. Therefore the correct type for your new example is then `void*(int)` which should again look familiar to you. However, gdb will print it as `void*()(int)`, where the `()` is in place of the omitted function name.

Comment: A function returning a `void *` and accepting an `int` should be IMO `void *(*)(int)`.

Comment: @6502: No, that would be a *pointer to a* function accepting an `int` and returning a `void`. Not the same thing. You wouldn't define your function as `void* (*foo)(int) { ... }`, would you?

Comment: You are right, that would be a pointer. And a pointer to a function is the only thing that you can for example store or pass to a function as parameter. However as we are talking about template parameters you can have also functions (sort of a second-class citizen type that cannot be used to declare a variable).